# How to read sas program files (.sas)?

Tags: python, sas

I want to import and read SAS program files (.SAS) in python notebook.
How can I do that? I am trying with `read_sas` but it's not working.
What is easiest way to do that?

Comment: .SAS files are pure text files. Read it the way you'd read any other text file.

Comment: `read_sas` is for reading SAS datasets. Reading SAS program files is done with `human.eyeball()`.

Answer (score 3):

A SAS program is merely a text file. Just open it up in any text editor. The sas7bdat data file is binary and contains the data (and metadata).

Answer (score 2):

proc import datafile="filepath" dbms="here type of file like csv or xlm etc..."out=""
replace;

delimiter='her delimiter like "," or "."or ":"  ' ;

run;

*you can open eny type  of file